# How to Customize screen Release AP Documents (AP501000) in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have a problem in customize screen Release AP Documents (screnid = AP501000). In case I have already create some additional fields in screen AP Bill And Adjusment, I was created 2 fields in DAC APTran (UsrJobOrderNbr and usrNoSeriFaktur). I create DAC Extension as named APTranExtension. and this below is the sintaks :

```
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AP;

namespace SGLCustomization
{
   [Serializable]
   public class APTranExtension: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTran>
   {
       #region UsrJobOrderNbr`enter code here`
       public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlField{}
       [PXDBString(25, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName="Job Order Nbr")]
       [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD,
                        Where<JobOrderNbr.status,
                            Equal<statusActive>>>),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.status),
              typeof(JobOrderNbr.usrJobOrderNoRef))]
      public string UsrJobOrderNbr
      {
          get;
          set;
      }

      #endregion
  }
}
```

I also create DAC Extension as named APTaxTranExtension, and this below is the sintaks :

```
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;

namespace SGLCustomization
{
   [Serializable]
   public class APTaxTranExtension: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.AP.APTaxTran>
   {
     #region UsrNoSeriFaktur
     public abstract class usrNoSeriFaktur : IBqlTable{}
     [PXDBString(50, IsFixed = true)]
     [PXUIField(DisplayName = "No Seri Faktur / Additional Narration")]
     public string UsrNoSeriFaktur { get; set; }
     #endregion
   }
}
```

I also create Extension DAC in GLTranExtension, to store values from APTranExtension and APTaxTranExtension. This below is the sintaks of my GLTranExtension :

```
using System;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.GL;

namespace SGLCustomization
{
   [Serializable]
  public class GLTranExtension: PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.GL.GLTran>
  {
      #region UsrJobOrderNbr

      public abstract class usrJobOrderNbr : IBqlField{}
      [PXDBString(25, IsFixed = true, IsUnicode = true)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="Job Order Nbr")]
      [PXSelector(typeof(Search<JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD,
                        Where<JobOrderNbr.status,
                            Equal<statusActive>>>),
                //typeof(JobOrderNbr.jobOrderNbrCD),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.customerID),
                typeof(JobOrderNbr.status))]
      public string UsrJobOrderNbr{get;set;}
      #endregion

      #region UsrNoSeriFaktur
      public abstract class usrNoSeriFaktur : IBqlTable { }
      [PXDBString(75, IsFixed = true)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "No Seri Faktur / Additional Narration")]
      public string UsrNoSeriFaktur { get; set; }
      #endregion

      #region UsrInvoiceNbr
      public abstract class usrInvoiceNbr : IBqlTable { }
      [PXDBString(60, IsFixed = true)]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Ref. / Customer Order")]
      public string UsrInvoiceNbr { get; set; }
      #endregion
  }
}
```

My goal is when I input transactions and then I release the document in screen Release AP Document (AP501000), all values in my new additional fields already sent into Journal Transaction screen (GL301000) also.

I already create APReleaseProcessExtension BLC to provide it, but it didn't work. This below is my APReleaseProcessExtension code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CT;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using SGLCustomization;
using SGLCustomization1;

namespace SGLCustomization1
{

  public class APReleaseProcessExtension: PXGraphExtension<APReleaseProcess>
  {
      public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDel(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor, Account> res, out PMRegister pmDoc);
      public List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor, Account> res, out PMRegister pmDoc, ReleaseDocProcDel del)
      {
          je.RowInserting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
          {
              GLTran glTran = e.Row as GLTran;
              APTran apTran = PXResult<APTran>.Current;
              if (glTran != null && apTran != null)
              {
                  APTranExtension apTex = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExtension>(apTran);
                  if (apTran != null && apTex.UsrJobOrderNbr != null)
                  {
                      GLTranExtension glTex = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExtension>(glTran);
                      glTex.UsrJobOrderNbr = apTex.UsrJobOrderNbr;
                  }
              }

              APInvoice api = PXResult<APInvoice>.Current;
              if (api != null && api.InvoiceNbr != null)
              {
                  GLTranExtension glTex = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExtension>(glTran);
                  glTex.UsrInvoiceNbr = api.InvoiceNbr;
              }

              APTaxTran apTax = PXResult<APTaxTran>.Current;
              if (apTax != null)
              { 
                  APTaxTranExtension apTaxEx = PXCache<APTaxTran>.GetExtension<APTaxTranExtension>(apTax);
                  if (apTax != null && apTaxEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur != null)
                  {
                      GLTranExtension glTex = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExtension>((GLTran)e.Row);
                      glTex.UsrNoSeriFaktur = apTaxEx.UsrNoSeriFaktur;

                  }
              }
          });
          return del(je, ref doc, res, out pmDoc);
      }
    #region Event Handlers
    #endregion
  }
}
```

Please help me to provide my goal,

Comment: so what is the error? or there is no error and it works as usual. Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: There is no error, but some values from my additional fields doesn't appear in Journal transaction's screen after released. It seems that my code doesn't works. Any suggestion how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code? is it invoking your row inserting handler when the method is being called?

Comment: I already try to debug, but it doesn't hit the breakpoint, even though I already attach the iispool for debug. so i can't trace the process. any ideas to solve this issue ?

Comment: from your code, it looks like you are adding a row inserting handler, so why not  you add the handler directly in the Journal Transaction BLC. In row inserting the base document field values may not be available; in this case i can recommend to use corresponding field updated event and retrieve your user values from base document.

Comment: Do you have a sample code to provide it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving into right direction but you've forgot to add [PXOverride] attribute. Without PXOverrideAttribute your method ReleaseDocProc will not be called. ReleaseDocProc of the base graph will be called instead.

You should always specify PXOverrideAttribute for methods that were overrided in extensions. Note that event handlers **should not** be marked with PXOverrideAttribute.

So the final code will look like that(I've modified methods signature as it was not compatible with the base method's signature in Acu 5.3U6):

```
public class APReleaseProcessExtension : PXGraphExtension<APReleaseProcess>
{
    public delegate List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProcDel(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor> res, bool isPrebooking, out List<INRegister> inDocs);
    [PXOverride]
    public List<APRegister> ReleaseDocProc(JournalEntry je, ref APRegister doc, PXResult<APInvoice, CurrencyInfo, Terms, Vendor> res, bool isPrebooking, out List<INRegister> inDocs, ReleaseDocProcDel del)
    {
        je.RowInserting.AddHandler<GLTran>((sender, e) =>
        {
            GLTran glTran = e.Row as GLTran;
            APTran apTran = PXResult<APTran>.Current;
            if (glTran != null && apTran != null)
            {
                APTranExtension apTex = PXCache<APTran>.GetExtension<APTranExtension>(apTran);
                if (apTran != null && apTex.UsrJobOrderNbr != null)
                {
                    GLTranExtension glTex = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExtension>(glTran);
                    glTex.UsrJobOrderNbr = apTex.UsrJobOrderNbr;
                }
            }
        });
        return del(je, ref doc,  res,  isPrebooking, out inDocs);
    }
}
```

I've also removed TaxTran and Invoice related extensions from this code to simplify it. You can easily return it.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Hello Dmitry,

I have modified my customization code correspoding to your final code.
It works great..

thank you very much for your assist.. :)

Comment: I'm glad that it helped you.  Please mark the answer correct :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbe in this forum,
How can I mark the answer as a correct answer ? 
So I can do your suggestion.. :)

Comment: I am a newbie too actually :)  So I don't know. There should be a button somewhere around the answer

Comment: I see the checklist button arround the answer, is this button that you mean ? I have marked it..

Comment: Hello Dmitry,, sorry for mention you again.
I have the same problem but this is in different screen, this is in screen Release AR Document. I describe more spesific in this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429196/how-to-customize-screen-ap-release-all-and-ar-relase-all-in-acumatica-erp-system

maybe if you have some reference to solve this problem, I'll apreciate and very thankfull of it. because it's urgently and already going live in the customer, Thanks